# What happened to the infection at the center of the Intergalactic Alpha station finally?

Tags: valerian-and-city-thousand-planets

Commander Arun, informs delegates about the center of the Intergalactic Alpha station has been infected by an unknown force, rendering it highly toxic. Troops sent into the area have not returned, and the infection is growing. Then next was Commander Arun was kidnapped and taken away by Pearls aliens and eventually movie characters forget about the infection.

**What happened to the infection at the center of the Intergalactic Alpha station finally?**

Comment: There was no infection. It was only a ruse by the Commander to stop people investigating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was no infection. It was simply a ruse used by Commander Filitt to justify to the council the use of troops and explosives at the centre of Alpha and to keep interested (e.g. nosy) aliens away while he mopped up the last evidence of his genocide.

> *“So when you found out that survivors from planet Mül were living in the heart of Alpha, you decided to erase any trace of your mistake, rather than accept the consequences. Right?”
>
> Filitt heard again his own voice in memory, now, as he watched the Pearls emerge from behind their wall. I want no survivors. Annihilate them all!*
>
> <sub><sup>[Valerian and the City of a Thousand Planets: The Official Movie Novelization](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33216612-valerian-and-the-city-of-a-thousand-planets)</sup></sub>

and

> *“It was the only way!” Filitt exploded. The words of justification he had hoped he would never have to speak were ripped from him. He stared wildly at the two agents, whose faces might as well have been carved into stone.
>
>   “Don’t you see?” he pleaded. “Admitting to an error on this scale would have exposed our government to colossal damages and compensation claims. Our economy would never recover!”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Valerian and the City of a Thousand Planets: The Official Movie Novelization](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33216612-valerian-and-the-city-of-a-thousand-planets)</sup></sub>

Comment: Neat. I couldn't post an answer, as I did read the book (ages ago of course), but I had trouble finding this passage in it...